# Uploading local static files to S3/GCS automatically in Next.js when deploying on Vercel

Tags: amazon-s3, webpack, next.js, google-cloud-storage, vercel

I have a website with a few somewhat large static files. Some are images I `import` into specific pages, some are files (e.g. .mp4) that I have configured webpack to load specifically:

```
// next.config.js:
// …
 webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(mp4|pdf|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|)$/,
      type: 'asset/resource',
      generator: {
        filename: 'static/[name].[hash][ext]',
      },
    });
    return config;
  },
// …
```

It works fine when self-hosting. I have made a build step to create a slim Docker image without static files, and uploading them to Google Cloud Storage instead.

However, I am exploring the option of deploying to Vercel instead, and when trying to deploy on Vercel, I encounter the following error:

```
NOW_SANDBOX_WORKER_MAX_LAMBDA_SIZE: The Serverless Function "[page path]" is 87.52mb which exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb.
```

I would like to maybe automatically upload the static files to a bucket (Google Cloud Storage or S3, I don't mind) and replace the paths. What is the correct way to go about this?